# Recent Win10 v20H2 update made comment's italicized monospaced content a cursive-like font?

Tags: support

Anyone else experiencing this and how do I change it, as modifying the font settings in Chromium-based Edge has no effect and the same output occurs in FireFox? I'm unsure what update could have resulted in this and no manual changes to the system font/appearance has occurred:

[image]

Comment: It's related to the recent font changes on SE - but I can't find the meta post discussing it.

Comment: @DavidPostill Is there any way to override it? Not sure if it helps, but Android still displays it correctly, both as a mobile site and viewing as a desktop site.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364881/135565 is the meta post. @JW0914 was there a recent platform update? I think that's what triggered off the issue on mine.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yeah, that was the post I couldn't find :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to override it? Not sure if it helps, but Android still displays it correctly, both as a mobile site and viewing as a desktop site.

The font is system specific.  So the font on Android will inherently look different on Windows.

> Windows continues to get Segoe, but we drop system-ui since it isn’t quite ready for primetime.
>
> Android gets Roboto, but we don’t specify it since it was clobbering Debian

Source: [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021)

> I'm unsure what update could have resulted in this and no manual changes to the system font/appearance has occurred:

It wasn’t a Windows update, it was a network wide Stack Exchange change, that happened on May 11th 2021